# Error "rzc generate exited with code -1073741819."

Tags: .net, visual-studio, runtime-error

Today I've tried to make a new migration in my project. I've added one database table and tried add-migration but I received this error.
It says it's location is
Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.CodeGeneration.targets 150
but I'm not even using .net2.0 in my project.
Haven't done anything else besides adding one class. It was working just fine yesterday.
What can I do now besides making the whole project once again?

Comment: -1073741819 = 0xC0000005, which is usually a bad pointer error.

Comment: @Rup Oh I don't think it's possible because I haven't changed a thing besides adding one class only with get; set;. What about this newstandard2.0 do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Opening Visual Studio Installer and running Repair for Visual Studio fixed it.